# run-time error'2147217900(80040e14)': ORA-09917:missing comma

Tags: vb6, project

I am using VB6 as frontend and oracle10g database as backend. Now
i am trying the above code in my vb project:

```
Con.Open "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=pune;User ID=system;Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True"
Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Rs.Open "insert into PARTNER_REQURIMENTS values('" & email.Text & "','" & Val(a1.Text) & "','" & Val(h1.Text) & "','" & ms.Text & "','" & r1.Text & "','" & mt.Text & "','" & mg.Text & "','" & el.Text & "','" & ef.Text & "','" & ai.Text & "','" & c1.Text & "','" & dr1.Text & "','" & s1.Text & "','" & d1.Text & "')", Con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Con.Execute "commit"
```

... but I get this error:

```
run-time error'2147217900(80040e14)':
ORA-09917:missing comma
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: My first suggestion is to look at the help and format your code correctly as code to make your question more readable. Second, not everyone on the site is a "Sir".

Comment: Looks like an Oracle error.  WHat does the documentation say it means?  Also VB6 is not VB.Net

Comment: Bear in mind if any of those textboxes contain a `'` the SQL will break and offer up the possibility of injection. Using a parameterized command object will prevent this.